# Knockout JS - list items without the parent <ul> element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a simple demo [application](http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5885/) with a foreach binding of "li" elements inside an "ul" element.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: sortedItems">
    <li>
        <div>
            <span data-bind="text: name"> 

        </div>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to create the same binding without a parent element?

Comment: You could create a component: 
 http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html.  It has a foreach in a template, but your view is cleaner.

Comment: There is no need to use neither `<div>` nor `<span>` in your code sample.  Why not bind the text of the `<li>` itself, in other words: if you don't want any extra elements, what's the point of including them?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use knockout's virtual element syntax for this purpose. See the first example on this [page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html).

```
<!-- ko foreach: sortedItems -->
    <li> ... </li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Where in my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5885/) do I put ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings in this case?

Comment: If and foreach can be applied to virtual elements by default, so you don't need to add that line. You only need to add the allowBindings statement if you want to use a custom binding on a virtual element.